# Centreon service' state : Maintaining last known state

Tags: python, monitoring, nagios

Maintaining last known state seems possible for hosts (using a plugin return code other than 0 or 1 : [Centreon blog post](http://blog.centreon.com/good-practices-how-to-develop-monitoring-plugin-nagios/)), but not for services.

So the problem is, **how to develop a plugin that wouldn't change the service state if not needed ?**

I'm retrieving the state from a file, but don't want to grab it if the file is too old. So in this case, when my Python plugin is scanning the file, I'd like it not to interfere with the current status.

EDIT : workarounds I thought about.

1. Exiting the Python plugin without making a system exit (is it even possible ??)
2. Exiting the plugin with an 'unknown' status. Could be ok, but in this case we lose the previous status in Centreon. If this later was a "critical" one, may not be the best idea.
3. ??

...or asking for a new functionality ;)

EDIT 2 : more information.

The Python plugin is generic, and made to retrieve informations from xml files. Those xml files are built with all a Nagios plugin needs :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Data>
        <CheckDate>1461939688</CheckDate>
        <Status>WARNING</Status>
        <Text>Warning on 3 disks</Text>
        <PerfData>'Disk 1'=34;10;50;0;</PerfData>
        <PerfData>'Disk 2'=21;10;50;0;</PerfData>
        <PerfData>'Disk 3'=11;10;50;0;</PerfData>
        <PerfData>'Disk 4'=0;10;50;0;</PerfData>
        <PerfData>'Disk 5'=3;10;50;0;</PerfData>
    </Data>
```

I'm comparing the given date to make sure informations aren't too old.

So basically, my Python plugin is just a xml parser, retrieving data and producing a standard Nagios output. We can call it a "xml to Nagios" converter ! Here's the output :

```
TEST WARNING: Errors on 3 disks | 'Disk 1'=34;10;50;0; 'Disk 2'=21;10;50;0; 'Disk 3'=11;10;50;0; 'Disk 4'=0;10;50;0; 'Disk 5'=3;10;50;0;

$ echo $?
1
```

It may seems useless (why not coding a plugin instead of using xml files ?), but :

1. we are retrieving informations from many sources, not all aware of
   the Nagios system
2. this allow plugins that are very slow to produce
   output. Otherwise, the Centreon server would product a timeout.

So, I'm not sure the whole code is relevant, just that I'm making this to have a proper exit "Nagios compliant" :

```
def return_status(status):
    if status == 'OK':
        return 0
    elif status == 'WARNING':
        return 1
    elif status == 'CRITICAL':
        return 2
    elif status == 'UNKNOWN':
        return 3
```

And further :
`sys.exit(return_status(status))`, status being of one of the permitted status : 'OK', 'WARNING', etc.

Comment: With a custom plugin the exit code is your choice.  A better example with code would be helpful to better understand what your are checking and how.

Comment: Thanks, JonB, I've edited my post. The problem is, exit codes other than 0, 1, 2 or 3 will produce a 'critical' status in Centreon, whereas for hosts it wouldn't change anything (which is what I'd also like for services).

Comment: At the risk of thinking you're over-thinking it you basically want to override the `<Status>WARNING</Status>` if `<CheckDate>1461939688</CheckDate>` is too old and return the status of whatever it was on the previous check?  I would also think that if the date in the XML file is too old you would want to know that so you could investigate why.

Comment: The idea was to keep both status and date of last check unchanged in Centreon (seems possible for hosts, see blog link). Override the current status would change the check date, it was not an acceptable option as it would let us think that a check had been performed, which isn't the case (also it would add a false value to the graph). The 'unknown' status may be the best option after all, as we indeed will have to investigate why the xml files are unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You're a little focused on the Host status which, in this case, has nothing to do with the Service status.  They're different and doubt the behavior will be altered.

I have written several plugins where a result file is created with a `cronjob` because the execution time exceeds the Centreon/Nagios limits.  The best way to deal with this is to check it's freshness (either by `stat` or the contents, as in your case) and alarm if it's too old.  I usually use `Unknown` but it depends on who's watching for it and how critical it might be if the file is too old.

For the `perfdata`, if the file is too old your values are meaningless.  Trying to keep them just to keep the graphs continuous is just for aesthetics.  Your real concern should be that the job that creates the file is working correctly before worrying about the data in it.